# Unable to access Dockerized Angular application in container

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:current-alpine3.10

RUN mkdir -p /dist/angular

WORKDIR /dist/angular

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8500

CMD ["npm","run","start:stage-ena-sso"]
```

**package.json**:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start:stage-ena-sso": "ng serve -o -c=stage-ena-sso --port=8500 --baseHref=/"
  }...
```

**Folder structure**:
[image]

**Command used to build the Docker image**:

```
docker build . -t ssoadminuiapp
```

**Command used to run the Docker image**:

```
docker run --rm -it  -p 8500:8500/tcp ssoadminuiapp:latest
```

**Check if container is running**:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8959e5180eba        ssoadminuiapp:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8500->8500/tcp   recursing_fermat
```

But accessing **localhost:8500** doesnt seem to work:
[image]

I'm really new to Docker, so any useful beginner-friendly tips/infos would be very appreciated.

Edit #1, this is the result after running docker run command:
[image]

Comment: when you run `docker run ..` what is your log?

Comment: have you checked the output log of the docker after you run it? Is the `start:stage-ena-sso` run correctly? try: `docker logs -f --tail 100 recursing_fermat` after you run the docker

Comment: Hi guys, I've updated the question with the log after running docker run.

Comment: Try to run the app using docker volume using the same run command and check of it is working.

Comment: @Henry please kill the container and try with ``docker run -dit  -p 8500:8500 ssoadminuiapp:latest``

Comment: @programandoconro I tried that command, and its still same

Comment: @souparnomajumder Sorry, what does docker volume mean? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

> Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:8500

Because your application is bound to `localhost` inside the container,
the port isn't available for port forwarding. That's like trying to
run a service on your host bound to `localhost` -- you can reach it
locally, but nothing remote can connect to it (and from a network
perspective, you host is "remote" from the container).

You'll need to configure the Angular server to bind to all addresses
in the container (`0.0.0.0`). I'm not sure exactly how to do this in
your application; when running `ng serve` from the command line there
is a `--host` option to set the bind address.

Comment: You mean something like this?
"start:stage-ena-sso": "ng serve -o -c=stage-ena-sso --port=8500 --baseHref=/ --host=0.0.0.0"

Comment: Thank you @larsks, you answer solved the issue :)

Comment: Excellent! I'm not familiar with Angular or npm so while I can tell you the solution I'm sorry I wasn't able to provide more explicit guidance. Glad you figured it out!